# Change SVG color in JQuery on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I've searched this topic on here, but my setup is a little different so I still have issues. Any help would be great! It's probably something so simple that I am over looking.

The code should make sense on what I am wanting to do. The SVG color change should happen in the click function.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav-container">
    <li class="nav-selected">
        <a href="#0">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#0">About</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#0">Projects</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#0">Blog</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#0">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-container li:first-of-type a::before {
    background-image: url(img/icon-1.svg);
}
.nav-container li:nth-of-type(2) a::before {
    background-image: url(img/icon-2.svg);
}
.nav-container li:nth-of-type(3) a::before {
    background-image: url(img/icon-3.svg);
}
.nav-container li:nth-of-type(4) a::before {
    background-image: url(img/icon-4.svg);
}
.nav-container li:nth-of-type(5) a::before {
    background-image: url(img/icon-5.svg);
}

.nav-container .nav-selected a {
    background-color: #222427;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.nav-container a').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    selected.parent('li').addClass('nav-selected').siblings('li').removeClass('nav-selected');

    // UPDATE COLOR SVG COLOR HERE
});
```

Comment: What do you have in `.cd-selected`?

Comment: Just fixed that. It was supposed to be the nav-selected. All it does is change the background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, know that SVG files do not have a `background` property like CSS; instead, SVG images use a `fill` property. Second, because you are using the SVG image in CSS background-image property, you can not change the `fill` property of the SVG element(s).

The best way to change `fill` would be to include the SVG code directly in the body and then control the appearance through CSS.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-container">
  <li class="nav-item nav-item-active">
    <a href="#0">
      <span>Home</span>
      <span>
        <svg class="nav-item-background>
          <!-- ... -->
        </svg>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-item .nav-item-background {
  fill: #fff;
}

.nav-item-active .nav-item-background {
  fill: #000;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.nav-container a').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    selected.parent('li').addClass('nav-item-active').siblings('li').removeClass('nav-item-active');
});
```